# Binary classification and ROC curve area less than .5

Tags: logistic, auc

Both my independent and dependent variables are binary. My result for classification table is 72% for predicted, and my ROC curve area is 0.389. Since <0.5 for ROC area is the worst for accuracy model, what should I do?

Comment: What is 72%? what are you measuring? If AUC is below 0.5, maybe there is some error in how you compute it. Have you by any chance inverted your predictions by mistake?

Comment: To have an ROC below 0.5 there must be some threshold where both classification error rates are below 0.5. However it is possible that for some threshold at least one prediction rate is above 0.5. So what you claim is possible.

Comment: No one can answer this without knowing what your problem is and what method(s) are you using.

Comment: Yup; the nice way to have ROC<0.5 is to accidentally swap class labels (as ALiX said), the painful way is to have a paradox problem (i.e. when test contains many objects with the same predictor values as in train but labelled differently).

Comment: I didn't mean for it to be an answer. I should have made it a comment to relate to ALiX's question.  I will change that.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Ok, fixed.

Comment: There doesn't have to be a mistake the ROC can rise above the 45 degree line a some point(s).  But It will have to be below it most of the time.  We can tell from th OPs remarks that the approach is not working well but to fix it we have to know a lot more aboutthe problem.

Comment: I'm using Multiple Linear Regression,then i check for the assumptions
1.hosher-lemeshow test
2.classification table
3.Area under the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve

after I remove my outlier, I'm still have problem with my Area under the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve.
my classification table is small which is the overall correctly classified percentage is 72.1%
and my  (ROC) curve is:

area = 0.355
std error = 0.012
asymptotic sig=0.000
since area is below than 0.5..so,what should I do..please help me since I'm a newly with statistics